# GeofenceIntentService not getting triggered on geofence enter

Tags: android, service, location, android-geofence

I'm trying to create geofences without google maps (just service that triggers PendingIntent when user is in geofence area). The problem is that I'm not able to get response when user enters geofence location. Here is my code from service class:

```
public class GeofenceBackgroundService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener,
    ResultCallback<Status> {

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent;
private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS = 500.0f;


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    /*mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);*/

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(10000)
            .setFastestInterval(5000)
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

    Geofence geofence = createGeofence();
    GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest(geofence);
    addGeofence(geofenceRequest);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Location changed " + location.getLatitude() +" " + location.getLongitude());
    }
}

private Geofence createGeofence() {
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
            .setCircularRegion(35.3140045, 103.4839695, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
            .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
            .setNotificationResponsiveness(1000)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build();
}

private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest(Geofence geofence) {
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build();
}

private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {
    if (geoFencePendingIntent != null)
        return geoFencePendingIntent;
    /*Intent intent = new Intent("com.receive.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
    PendingIntent geoFencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return geoFencePendingIntent;*/
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}


private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(googleApiClient, request, createGeofencePendingIntent()).setResultCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
    } else {
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}}
```

Also I tried to use both IntentService and Broadcast receiver and declared them properly in android manifest file

Comment: `GeofenceIntentService not getting triggered on geofence enter`. There is no GeofenceIntentService in your code. What do you mean exactly? Which function is not triggered?

Comment: GeofenceTransitionsIntentService is not getting triggered

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`